# How would i get the value from the callback URL using ASP Classic

Tags: json, https, asp-classic, webservice-client, getresponse

thank you in advance. Can anyone help me with this problem,
i need to get the value from the callback URL. The callback URL look like this. that parameters from the callback URL is sent by the third party.

```
     "https://www.viewmyrecord.com/Texting/GetReply.asp?from=1561234567&to=15698745642&text=Hi 
      Kid,Reminder November 22, 2019 w/ REN, MD at 11:00 am&datetime=Nov 11 2019 10:17PM&cost=0.00"
```

I need to parse the value of "**from**","**to**","**text**","**datetime**" and "**cost**". And save it to text file. I don't have any idea about this. but my "**GetReply.asp**" looks like this.

```
      <%
       If Request.TotalBytes > 0 Then
       Dim lngBytesCount,try
       lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
       Response.Write BytesToStr(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))

       dim fs,tfile,loc,locadd,loctime,loctime1,nameFile,datename

       datDate = Now()
       locadd = Trim(FormatDateTime(datDate, 1)) 
       loctime = FormatDateTime(datDate, 4)
       loctime1 =  stripNonNumeric(FormatDateTime(Now, 3))
       nameFile = "\\85new\Accts85new\Texting\Reply\"
       datename = Trim(loctime1&"-"&locadd&".txt")
       loc = "\\85new\Accts85new\Texting\Reply\"&loctime1&"-"&locadd&".txt"
       set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       set tfile=fs.CreateTextFile(loc)
       tfile.WriteLine(try)
       tfile.close
       set tfile=nothing
       set fs=nothing
       end if

      Function BytesToStr(bytes)
      Dim Stream
      Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
      Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
      Stream.Open
      Stream.Write bytes
      Stream.Position = 0
      Stream.Type = 2 'adTypeText
      Stream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
      BytesToStr = Stream.ReadText
      try = BytesToStr
      Stream.Close
      Set Stream = Nothing
      End Function

      Function stripNonNumeric(inputString)
          Set regEx = New RegExp
          regEx.Global = True
          regEx.Pattern = "\D"
          stripNonNumeric = regEx.Replace(inputString,"")
      End Function

    %>
```

On that "**GetReply.asp**" im getting a response of "**200 ok**"
Can anyone tell me what am i missing or lacking with those code. 
I will really appreciate it. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hi, Looks like you're taking the hard way here... First you should make sure your  "text" and "datetime" parameters are URLencoded. After, it's just a question of retrieving those parameters using request.querystring() and write them to file using FileSystemObject. I don't see any need for an ADO stream...

Comment: Hello @ChrisBE, im so sorry can you please explain it in detailed. Because honestly i don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, I'm not sure why you go through all the pain of an ADO Stream.
As far as I can tell from your code, all you need to do is something like this:

```
dim strFrom, strTo, strText, strDatetime

strFrom = request.querystring("from")
strTo = request.querystring("to")
strText = request.querystring("text")
strDatetime = request.querystring("datetime")
```

Then use the FileSystemObject as you currently do to write these values to file.

But if you get these values from a third-party, I would expect at least the "text" parameter to be URLencoded...

Comment: Hi **@ChrisBE**, thank you so much for your reply i really appreciate it and it helps me alot. Now i am getting the values from the callback URL. Thank you

Comment: @RaiAnne If this answer helped you solve your question, use the green tick next to it to mark it as such.